# find if the value in pandas column is in another column's list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
    ID       dates                              holidays
0  ABC  01/01/2022  [12/25/2021, 01/01/2022, 01/17/2022]
1  DEF  03/17/2022  [01/01/2022, 06/01/2022, 27/01/2022]
```

I need to create another column `isHoliday` with bool value if the value in column dates is in holidays list for that id. I am trying to use the code below but it shows an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`:

```
df['isHoliday'] = np.where(df['dates'].isin(df['holidays']), True, False)
```

Is it any way to find whether the columns dates value is in the list that corresponds each ID?

Answer (score 5):

[`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) works really well here:

```
df['isHoliday'] = df.eval('dates in holidays.explode()')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    ID       dates                              holidays  isHoliday
0  ABC  01/01/2022  [12/25/2021, 01/01/2022, 01/17/2022]       True
1  DEF  03/17/2022  [01/01/2022, 06/01/2022, 27/01/2022]      False
```

Benchmarks:

```
def scott():
    [d in l for d, l in zip(df['dates'], df['holidays'])]

def shubham():
    pd.DataFrame([*df['holidays']]).eq(df['dates'], axis=0).any(1)

def charles():
    df[['dates','holidays']].apply(lambda row: row['dates'] in row['holidays'], axis=1)

def richardec():
    df.eval('dates in holidays.explode()')

###

%timeit scott()
# 5.99 µs ± 302 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

%timeit shubham()
# 547 µs ± 10.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit charles()
# 525 µs ± 2.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit richardec()
# 971 µs ± 71.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

So mine is the shortest, but Scott's is the fastest!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
df['isholiday'] = [d in l for d, l in zip(df['dates'], df['holidays'])]
```

Output:

```
    ID       dates                              holidays  isholiday
0  ABC  01/01/2022  [12/25/2021, 01/01/2022, 01/17/2022]       True
1  DEF  03/17/2022  [01/01/2022, 06/01/2022, 01/27/2022]      False
```

Comment: Look at the benchmarks in my answer @Scott.

Answer (score 3):

The source of the issue is that the `.isin()` method does not vectorize its argument, so it's checking if each date is in the whole series of lists, and in the process I believe it casts the argument to a set for speed purposes. Sets only accept immutable values, and lists are mutable, so it gives the unhashable type error.

I think you'll want to use an apply instead:

```py
df['isHoliday'] = df[['dates','holidays']].apply(
    lambda row: row['dates'] in row['holidays'], 
    axis=1
)
```

In this case you don't need the np.where because the condition itself returns a series of `True`s and `False`s.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a vectorized approach:

```
df['isholiday'] = pd.DataFrame([*df['holidays']]).eq(df['dates'], axis=0).any(1)
```

Result

```
    ID       dates                                holidays  isholiday
0  ABC  01/01/2022    [12/25/2021, 01/01/2022, 01/17/2022]       True
1  DEF  03/17/2022  [01/01/2022,  06/01/2022,  27/01/2022]      False
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, Scott's is 6 times faster than this.

Comment: @richardec Yep! List comprehension is generally faster in case of complex data types.

Comment: Wow... you know, I don't think I've ever tried to unpack a pd.Series like this. +1

Comment: Hey @ScottBoston, Thanks! Just a little less typing is involved in unpacking syntax otherwise it doesn't makes any difference performance-wise :-)